# Can I configure TypeScript to automatically prefix private members with underscores in js output?

Tags: typescript

I'm making a small in-house JavaScript library for work which uses TypeScript. I'd like for the TypeScript compiler to automatically prefix private member names with underscores in its output so as to discourage their use in production. I tried searching for an answer myself, but most results lead to code style discussions.

I know I could prefix them myself, but it would be significantly nicer to let the compiler handle this so that my source code is less muddied with underscores everywhere. Again, their use in production would be discouraged so this wouldn't affect my end users at all.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: No not possible

Comment: You can probably make use of the [TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)

Edit: You can find some examples of transforms via [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14419#issuecomment-298814505).